# Click on links in each row of a table

Tags: python, selenium

On a webpage there is a table, and each row has a link. I want to iterate thru the table and click on each link in the rows and open it in a different tab.

This is the table, the first item in each row is a link:

[image]

```
table =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpathofthetable")

for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
    print([td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_xpath(".'][text()]")
```

Comment: try using control_key_down+click.that opens link in new tab

Comment: can you provide the link of the table.

Answer (score 0):

The below code may works.

```
table =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpathofthetable")

for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
   link = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td//a")
   print(link.text)
   action = ActionChains(driver)
   action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Assumed the link is an anchor tag.